# Sample size in categorical data

Tags: sampling, inference

I have a population of bank disbursements (2,848 loans) occured in 2016-02 from three regions. The proportions of disbursements by region 39.29%, 30.13% and 30.58% respectively.

I would like to study the proportion of non-compliance (for simplicity 0 if there is no compliance and 1 elsewhere) with bank internal policies at the moment of credit assessment by region and infer if H0: there is no evidence that the level of compliance differs significantly among these three regions.

What approach(es) can I take in order to sample the population (size, proportion, etc) and conduct the study?

Answer (score 0):

The goal of inferential statistics, in this case, would be to conclude whether or not a significant difference exists between any two groups. We gathers sample of data and assess how strong the evidence is that the two groups differ.

If you have the population, then there is no need to do inferential statistics. If you know the proportions of non-compliance in each group, then you can simply assess from a real-world perspective whether or not the difference is significant. You need not conduct any test because you know that the proportions of non-compliance are different. Now your question becomes, "Is it different enough for me to care," at which point the answer to that is based only on your subject-matter expertise rather than on statistical methodology.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I don't know the proportion of non-compliance cases for each region. In an ideal scenario, I would analyze each credit file (2,848) and perhaps visit the debtor in order to check the level of compliance. But, that's not possible because of budget constraints.